# How to create a directory in root directory using python.pathlib.Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

How do I create a directory in root directory using `python.pathlib.Path`?

```
>>> c = Path.home().parent / 'test'
>>> c
PosixPath('/home/test')
>>> c.mkdir()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    c.mkdir()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1248, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/test'
```

Comment: With the appropriate permissions?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I am looking for a pythonic way to do `sudo mkdir /home/test` but without having to type the sudo password where possible. The approach I can think of is to use `subprocess.run()`. However, is there a another python alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is works if you run your script with sudo.

Or you can use `os` module:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

c = str(Path.home().parent / 'test')
os.system(f"sudo mkdir {c}")
```

Comment: This won't work if `c` contains a space or any other kind of special shell-command character.